# Can I implement the input and display for some custom icons by UITextField?

Tags: iphone

I want to implement the input and display for some custom icons such as ":)", ":(", "@name", etc. Can I finish this work by UITextField? or is there any open source library can be refered?

Answer (score 0):

You could hook up the action of valueChanged for the text field to a method which scans the text, finding the range of any of those smilies etc in the text, and if found, replace the characters to corresponding emoji characters?